# Finding string-key in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

1) I have this Javascript array:

```
lang=new Array();
lang["sq"]="Albanian";
lang["ar"]="Arabic";
lang["en"]="English";
lang["ro"]="Romanian";
lang["ru"]="Russian";
```

2) In some other process, there is a returned value in a variable:

```
result.detectedSourceLanguage = 'en';
```

3) Now, i want to print the language full name by doing this:

```
alert(lang[result.detectedSourceLanguage]);
```

The dialog displays: **undefined**

Any ideas?

BTW: im using JQuery, so JQuery solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Did you try using index's? 0,1,2,3? When declaring variable did you use VAR? Try also calling that variable "resultDetectedSourceLanguage"... Dont know what else to say... :)

Comment: May be check that you have the array defined by the time you are trying to access it. BTW What do you mean by "in some other process"?

Comment: if i call:
alert(lang['en']);
it prints English as it should.

The problem is when i do this:
alert(lang[var1]);

(where var1 holds 'en' value).

Comment: Well that assertion is impossible; regardless of your misuse of Array (should be Object, {}), JavaScript does allow this, and your code above does work as expected. There is something else happening; post a full test case that fails.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An `Array` uses integer indexes.  You probably want an `Object`, which supports string indexes:

```
lang=new Object();
lang["sq"]="Albanian";
lang["ar"]="Arabic";
lang["en"]="English";
lang["ro"]="Romanian";
lang["ru"]="Russian";

// or

lang = {
    'sq': 'Albanian',
    'ar': 'Arabic',
    // ...
    'ru': 'Russian'
};
```

(The latter example is probably better as more JS programmers would be happy with it.)

Comment: Just a note on why the OP sometimes worked: In JS Arrays are objects, so you can attach arbitrary properties to them as you can with any other object. As was found though, these additional properties can get lost if the array is serialized to its normal `['val 1', 'val 2', 'val 3, ...]` syntax. Its likely that somewhere in JQuery or elsewhere a serialization/deserialization is happening to the array, and the additional properties are lost.

Comment: I know an `Array` is an `Object`, but really, you should treat it as a sequential array (like `std::vector` in C++'s STL) and not an associative array (like `std::map` in C++'s STL or PHP-like arrays), to avoid confusion.  Serialization/conversion may be the problem as you suggest, Adam.

Answer (score 3):

This script generates a message box (checked in IE & FF) that says "English":

```
lang = new Array();
lang["sq"] = "Albanian";
lang["ar"] = "Arabic";
lang["en"] = "English";
lang["ro"] = "Romanian";
lang["ru"] = "Russian";

detectedSourceLanguage = 'en';

alert(lang[detectedSourceLanguage]);
```

The only problem could be the `result` object.

Comment: i added
alert(lang[String(detectedSourceLanguage)]);

that worked out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the type and value of `result` (and `result.detectedSourceLanguage`). It could be one of the following

- `result` is not defined
- `result` is not an object or doesn't have any attribute named `detectedSourceLanguage`
- Value of `result.detectedSourceLanguage` is not a string or there's no such key in `lang` (then it's supposed to return `undefined` for `alert(lang[result.detectedSourceLanguage]);` )

BTW, your problem has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: that has nothing to do with the prob. if i call:
alert(lang['en']);
it prints English as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try alerting result.detectedSourceLanguage immediately prior to its use.  There is a chance that it doesn't equal what you expect it to.  This should work.

Comment: actually that alert displays: en

Comment: what browser are you running this against?